# VB code detects only one HTML element and ignores the rest

Tags: html, vb.net, htmlelements

I’m using VB to detect all `textarea` elements in a document and edit their value.

This is the code:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser4.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
  MsgBox(Element.GetAttribute("name"))
  If (Element.GetAttribute("name") = "field1") Then
    Element.SetAttribute("Value", Message)
  ElseIf (Element.GetAttribute("name") = "field2") Then
    Element.SetAttribute("Value", My.User.Name.Replace("/", "~"))
  End If
Exit For
Next Element
```

As you can see, the two `textarea` elements I’m interested in have the `name` of `field1` and `field2`, however my code **only detects and edits `field1`**.

I’ve tried adding more elements, and it still doesn’t detect anything except of `field1`.

This is the document I’m searching in:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
  $data = $_POST['field1'];
  file_put_contents($_POST['field2'] . '.txt', "");
  $ret = file_put_contents($_POST['field2'] . '.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <textarea style="width: 800px;" name="field1"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($field1) ?></textarea>
  <textarea style="width: 800px;" name="field2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($field2) ?></textarea>
  <input type="submit" style="width: 150px;" name="submit" value="Save Data">
  <input type="reset" style="width: 150px;" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

I’m very confused. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually looping. Try:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser4.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
  MsgBox(Element.GetAttribute("name"))
  If (Element.GetAttribute("name") = "field1") Then
    Element.SetAttribute("Value", Message)
  ElseIf (Element.GetAttribute("name") = "field2") Then
    Element.SetAttribute("Value", My.User.Name.Replace("/", "~"))
  End If
Next 'loop to next element
```

For each documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/5ebk1751.aspx

Comment: You're right, I was using this code for a different purpose and I don't have much knowledge in VB looping. Thank you.